# UITableViewCells with long labels won't indent in editing mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

I have a plain (UITableViewStylePlain) UITableView  with basic (UITableViewCellStyleDefault) UITableViewCells in iOS 6.1. When it enters editing mode, its cells indent as I want them to. But only if all cell labels are short: if one is long enough to be clipped on the right side, none of the table cells will indent any more.

For instance:

1. table with one cell: (SHORT) => indents i.e. works
2. table with two cells: (LONG) (SHORT) => neither cell indents i.e. does not work

What simple steps can remedy this situation? E.g., it appears as if I cannot change the preset size properties on a basic, i.e. non-custom table view cell in Xcode.

**UPDATE:** Here are two images that further describe the problem (1st: correct case, 2nd: incorrect case):

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:** It has turned out that the root cause is not the lengths of labels. Instead it seems to be about my async. KVO handling in relation to this table view. My `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` calls a getter on the cell's underlying managed (Core Data) object. It seems that managed objects' default getters in turn call their own setters, probably when [faulted](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) objects are realized. Because of the way my KVO is set up, this in leads to another call of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. As it so happens, only the 2nd case involved a KVO notification and the ensuing recursive call may cause the problem (it seems slightly odd in any case) ...

Comment: Can you post any image , describing your problems well.

Comment: @Ankit thx for your comment. I have added two images. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by "prefetching" the underlying managed objects in the constructor of the table view's data source. I do this by accessing the property that is displayed in the table cell. That way the first KVO notifications are triggered in a context where they cannot lead to unwanted recursive invocations of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If there is a better (more elegant) way to handle the situation, I'd still be interested to learn about it.